# HTTP Status Code to be returned for a REST Service when the URL Parameter Key is invalid

Tags: web-services

What is the HTTP Status Code to be returned for a REST Service when the URL Parameter Key is invalid? and What should be the HTTP Status Code returned if the parameter keys or the tag names are invalid for JSON or XML requests?

Answer (score 0):

One of our system provides unified RESTful API to end users, in this case, it returns 400 Bad Request with detailed description that what's the unexpected parameter/json key or value and the suggested resolution.

If the API is not public to end users, you can consider not explain more information. Because this may help bad guys gather sensitive information for attack.

Answer (score 0):

In general, when there is a problem with the request you return one of the 4xx status codes.

In all your examples the most appropriate status to return is simply `400 Bad Request`. In the body of your response you can include additional information regarding the nature of the error.

Check for instance this url for a list of the status codes: http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html